# UWP Change Color in a Toggle Button in code

Tags: colors, uwp, toggle

i need to change the default color of touggle button.
I can't do this in XAML code because i receive the color from json file at run time.

So, can i change the  default color in vb or c# code ?
Not the Back or Fore color but the switch color.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> So, can i change the default color in vb or c# code ?

The switch color for [`Toggle​Button`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton) is actually the background color changed by visual states. To change its default color, you can redefine the theme resources used by visual states that influence this color code behind as follows:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Application.Current.Resources["ToggleButtonBackgroundChecked"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    Application.Current.Resources["ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPointerOver"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    Application.Current.Resources["ToggleButtonBackgroundCheckedPressed"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

XAML

```
 <ToggleButton              
     Click="Button_Click"
     Content="ToggleButton" />
```

More details please reference [ToggleButton styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299157.aspx).

If you are using [`Toggle​Switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch) you need update the following two:

```
Application.Current.Resources["ToggleSwitchFillOnPointerOver"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
Application.Current.Resources["ToggleSwitchFillOn"]= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Try find the resources you need to change in the style template.

Comment: I had tried but nothing is changed 
I must to write any other rows ?

Comment: @DanieleP. Did you use `ToggleButton` control or `ToggleSwitch`? What's your uwp app target version?

Comment: OPS i use  ToggleSwitch !!

Comment: @DanieleP. Please check my updated reply for `ToggleSwich`. Different scenario need to change difference theme resources.

Comment: Now is ok ??
Sorry i don't' know how use it